# What do you call these types of images?

Tags: style-identification, terminology

What do call these types of graphics? I'm referring to the green part of this image. I found it on a website.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time you call shapes like these [banners](https://www.google.com/search?q=banner&num=20&safe=active&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0neiA77nLAhXLNSYKHcTcAiEQ_AUIBygB&biw=1920&bih=955). Since it's taller than it is wide, you could call it a [vertical banner](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&biw=1920&bih=955&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=vertical+banner&oq=vertical+banner&gs_l=img.3..0l10.30007.31426.0.31498.15.12.0.2.2.0.105.843.10j2.12.0....0...1c.1.64.img..1.14.836.62a_0XZpg0Q).

You can find a lot of tutorials using these terms.

Comment: Thanx a lot zach

Comment: @حميديعقوبي You can mark an answer as correct by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. This will show it as "Accepted" and give both the person answering and you, the asker, reputation

Answer (score 2):

You can call this kind of graphic "**[vertical ribbon](https://www.google.ca/search?q=vertical%20ribbon%20banner&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1k_z91LvLAhUGtYMKHfZSAigQ_AUIBygB&biw=1434&bih=822)**" if you want a precise term and the same look. They can be any width and can be used as banners too.

That kind of design with the pointy ends is easier to find by searching for "ribbon" or "vertical ribbon banner".

[Example:](http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-smooth-ribbon-with-borders)

[image: vertical ribbon banner]

[Example:](http://www.shutterstock.com/s/vertical+ribbon/search-vectors.html)

[image]